# ASP.NET Entity Framework trying to update single column

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET Entity Framework and I am trying to update a single column with the following code:

```
[HttpGet]
public void MarkOffline(string online)
{
     Users user = new Users { email = online, isOnline = false };
     db.Entry(user).Property("isOnline").IsModified = true;
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I get this error:

> Member 'IsModified' cannot be called for property 'isOnline' because
>   the entity of type 'Users' does not exist in the context. To add an
>   entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of `DbSet<Users>`.

The part I don't know how to do:

> To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of
>   `DbSet<Users>`.

How do I fix my problem?

Comment: Is email your primary key?

Comment: like the instruction says, "call the add or attach method of Users" e.g. `db.Users.Attach(...` Also I think Users is probably the table class. To create a single user I'd imagine you'd want to do `new User {...` (without the s).

Comment: Since the user is new you add the user by doing Users.Add(user), this creates the object. If you want to modify an existing user then you need to get the from the DbSet, var user = Users.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Smith");

Comment: @CodeCaster email is not the primary key, however I am looking to update based on email address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update like this, you'll need to Attach the entity where the entity has its primary key set.

Given you don't have its primary key but only one of its (unique, hopefully) fields, you need to query the record first and then update it:

```
var existing = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.email == email);
existing.IsOnline = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```

That being said, this is not how you record a user's online status in a web application. You rather update a user's `LastAction` timestamp with each action they perform, and mark a user as offline at runtime when their `LastAction` is more than N seconds or minutes ago.